# Sencha GXT Combo Box without Data Type

Tags: java, extjs, combobox, gxt

I'm using Sencha GXT 3.0.0 + Hibernate.

I have static values to insert into a ComboBox, for example: names of states from USA,
and I DONT want to create a (base) class a.k.a. data type (I have my reasons...)

I have something like this in mind:

```
String vector=["Alabama","California","Wyoming"];
private ComboBox<String> comboBox1;
```

On [Sencha GXT Web Site](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3acombobox) we can see an example

But I dont want to create the "State" class.

Is it possible?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution? I need the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleComboBox should do you.  It actually still creates a base class of type SimpleComboValue, but it does all that behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

```
LabelProvider<String> lb = new LabelProvider<String>() {

            @Override
            public String getLabel(String item) {
                return item;
            }

        };
comboBox1 = new SimpleComboBox<String>(lb);
comboBox1.add(lb.getLabel("Alabama"));
comboBox1.add(lb.getLabel("California"));
comboBox1.add(lb.getLabel("Wyoming"));
comboBox1.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);

addFormField(comboBox1, "myField",HtmlDataPosition.RIGHT );
```